# Invalid cast exception on command.Parameters.GetValue<long>

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have some ADO.Net code as below, it successfully execute the SP in DB, while it throws exception at tenantId, please guide me on it.

```
            command.Parameters.Input.BigInt(ParameterConstants.TenantId)
                                    .BigInt(ParameterConstants.PartyId, tenant.PartyId)
                                    .Varchar(ParameterConstants.TenantCode, tenant.TenantCode)
                                    .BigInt(ParameterConstants.PharmaId, tenant.PharmaId)
                                    .BigInt(ParameterConstants.UserId, userProfileId);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var tenantId = command.Parameters.GetValue<long>(ParameterConstants.TenantId);
```

at `var tenantId` it throws cast exception `System.InvalidCastExceptio`...
exact exception `Specified cast is not valid.`

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ...Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the full exception message?

Comment: I added exact exception.

Comment: what if you add output parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetValue<long>` method isn't probably handling a `NULL` value. That `GetValue<>` is probably a custom method (not Microsoft) you or someone else wrote, so I don't know how to fix it. You could try:

```
var tenantId = command.Parameters.GetValue<long?>(ParameterConstants.TenantId);
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess will be that the database type and the class type for TenantId are not compatible. For example, string vs int vs long.

Comment: No that's @TenantId bigint=null,